# Open field usage of Google Resonance Audio SDK

Tags: audio

is there a scenario where we can use the Google Resonance Audio SDK not with headphones, but with real speakers (e.g. mounted in a 360° cyrcle setting)?

Or are all algorithms not working for real speaker outputs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Resonance Audio is optimized for headphone playback. For example, HRTF processing is done in the Ambisonics domain, without generating (virtual) speaker signals - this is because it is a much more efficient way of generating binaural output.

However, in the Resonance Audio open source release, the [Ambisonic Codec](https://github.com/resonance-audio/resonance-audio/blob/master/resonance_audio/ambisonics/ambisonic_codec.h) class can readily be used to decode Ambisonics to any arbitrary loudspeaker array. To use that with the rest of the Resonance Audio system, however, it would be necessary to modify/extend the audio processing graph by adding a new decoder node.

Please, feel free to add a feature request and, depending on popularity, we might consider adding that in the future!